# How does an old Internet Explorer know of a newer version in context of X-UA-compatible

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, x-ua-compatible

My company is still using Internet Explorer 9 (yes, should be upgraded, we know) due to policy.

We now have a web application, which only works well when having set

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

**My question**

How does IE 9 know of the latest IE version (= Edge) as Edge did not exist when IE 9 came out? Via Windows Updates? Or...?

Comment: In this context, "edge" refers to "the highest mode supported by the browser.  In the case of IE9, that leads to IE9 standards mode.  In IE8, however, it's IE8 standards mode.   To learn more, see [Understanding legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx#dcmodes).

Originally, it was an internal value used by the QA team to test browser behavior in multiple versions.  It was actively discouraged until ~IE10, when the guidance changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what it seems, just a case of an overused word.

Firstly, Edge is not the latest version of Internet Explorer. It is a new browser that was forked from IE. It is "the latest IE version" the way that Chrome is the latest Webkit version.

The "Edge" that is referred to in that metatag is which rendering engine that should be used. It just means use the latest possible rendering engine (IE had the ability to fallback to previous rendering engines for compatibility reasons). In IE 9, this means force the site to be processed in IE 9 mode, and disregard any heuristic that may say that the site works better in IE 8.